# Regarding C++ Libraries Installation in Red Hat Linux WITHOUT INTERNET

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been trying to install Codeblocks and C++ libraries in the Red Hat Linux. It's been 1 week that I am trying to find a way to install them, specifically OpenCV. Is there any way to install them without internet? If not, which are the best in-built libraries which can be used in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having software packages/repositories installed (or built on your own from another computer that has internet access) or on a network fileshare/external harddrive no. The `yum repos` download their files through mirror URLs, where these package repositories are stored and require internet access to communicate to these mirrors.

If you don't want to `yum install`, you can build from source by copying over the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) from another machine onto your system without internet access and building from source, but it may not work depending on the package dependencies of OpenCV and if they are available on your system.

The only built in C++ libraries without having any software package installed or building from source is the standard library.